# How do I mark an image non-redistributable

Tags: docker

Say I'm a software vendor and I am wanting to host images of my software on a Container Registry that I control, but want to prevent distribution of these images by them being uploaded to other public or private Container Registries.

Much like Microsoft (and other vendors) does it; their "base layers" are skipped by default when uploading to a private registry.

```
de5b52133faf: Pushed
d2425dc4f846: Skipped foreign layer
a7ba3db29ebb: Skipped foreign layer
```

How does Docker know this?   How is it set up in other words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pull the manifests for these images, you'll see that the urls field is populated for those layers:

```
$ regctl image manifest --platform windows/amd64 golang
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 7024,
    "digest": "sha256:ba630408bc63a555f6ad4fae6a2f5eab8fcba7cb050ac51b15d2e607f9fe8591"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.foreign.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 1718332879,
      "digest": "sha256:4612f6d0b889cad0ed0292fae3a0b0c8a9e49aff6dea8eb049b2386d9b07986f",
      "urls": [
        "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/servercore/blobs/sha256:4612f6d0b889cad0ed0292fae3a0b0c8a9e49aff6dea8eb049b2386d9b07986f"
      ]
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.foreign.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 720933935,
      "digest": "sha256:db4edcf0861ff3fdc41851a5a218965ecb2ab6cf4ec9448fb80cc4b6792fd46c",
      "urls": [
        "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/servercore/blobs/sha256:db4edcf0861ff3fdc41851a5a218965ecb2ab6cf4ec9448fb80cc4b6792fd46c"
      ]
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 1362,
      "digest": "sha256:433d24156d44dde3b3c6c0094ba5824a315286ae537c68f272e464fc426510f6"
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 1387,
      "digest": "sha256:2a2b02a688b62e8e70705b5d1eeaae912e44e9fb6dd72cfefc104982d61c555f"
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 1329,
      "digest": "sha256:d2bbc05d8cabd13ca38228cb52a2a4c1144c7a230b2c59e2e11b26f1f144f5dd"
    },
    ...
```

You can see that field in the [image-spec descriptor definition](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/4f04bc480833e58d3b8895d6a232c90cc2cf79e7/specs-go/v1/descriptor.go#L33). I'm not aware of any public tools to generate manifests with this field. At the very least it's not an option when building from a Dockerfile with `docker build` or buildkit. So you may be writing your own tool to generate these images.

My understanding from conversations with Microsoft employees is they feel this was a mistake and are working hard to undo this from their images because of the workflows that it breaks. For example, any user in a disconnected environment can't pull the image with normal tools. And yet the layers themselves could be pulled with a simple curl command, so there's not a lot of added security being provided by this.